# Java Concurrency on Android

Tags: java, android, concurrency

I am trying to make a android app example which demostrates concurrency problem, but it is weird to me that my code shows correct result instead of errorous result caused by race condition. The followings are my code, I read about think in Java(around page 1150)

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private breadBaker bB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("shanwu","Thread Test Starts!");
        bB = new breadBaker();
        bB.makeBread();
        breadBuyer TA = new breadBuyer();
            try{
                Thread a =new Thread(TA); 
                Thread b =new Thread(TA); 
                Thread c =new Thread(TA); 
                Thread d =new Thread(TA); 
                Thread e =new Thread(TA);
                Thread f =new Thread(TA);
                Thread g =new Thread(TA);
                Thread h =new Thread(TA);
                Thread i =new Thread(TA);
                Thread j =new Thread(TA);
                a.start();
                b.start();
                c.start();
                d.start();
                e.start();
                f.start();
                g.start();
                h.start();
                i.start();
                j.start();
                bB.makeBread();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    class breadBaker{
        private int breadCount;
        public breadBaker(){
            breadCount = 3;
        }
        public void makeBread(){
            breadCount++;
            Log.d("shanwu","make one bread, current bread count: "+breadCount);
        }
        public void giveBread(){
            breadCount--;
            Log.d("shanwu","sold one bread, current bread count: "+breadCount);
        }
        public int getBreadCount()
        {
            return breadCount;
        }
    }

    class breadBuyer implements Runnable{
        public void buyBread(){
            bB.giveBread();
        }
        public void waitInLine(){
　　　　　　　　　　// Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(bB.getBreadCount() > 0){
                buyBread();
            }
            else
            {
                waitInLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I basically learn from contents of Think in Java, and try to make it work on Android... please point out what seems to be the problem, I thought the breadCount will become negative value due to race condition, but it's not, it works correctly...

Comment: Eh, do you really only make one bread and then expect it to fail? Race conditions *may* occur, they don't occur all the time, that's the whole irritating bit about them.

Comment: Your threads are starved :P

Comment: you have a check in your thread if(bB.getBreadCount() > 0){
                buyBread();
            }
            else
            {
                waitInLine();
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the book from beginning of Concurrency again, it says it's hard to make errorous demo code, but we still have to pay attention to concurrency problem, or we will get ourselves in trouble later.